# Not printing outside of if statement

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I am making my own version of make. I allow for some arguments to be passed via command line.

I am working on it in chunks. I am setting the fileName right now

I have the following code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *fileName = NULL;
    char fileFlag[2];

    strcpy(fileFlag, "-f");
    printf("%s\n", fileFlag);
    if (argc == 1) {
        fileName = (char *) malloc(sizeof("Makefile"));
        strcpy(fileName, "Makefile");
        printf("One arg %s\n", fileName);
    }
    printf("\n%s", fileName);
    return 0;
}
```

When it runs I get the following output.

```
-f
One arg Makefile
```

Shouldn't it print another line?

Comment: `fileFlag` isn't big enough to hold two chars and a nul terminator.

Comment: Sorry, was wrong about `sizeof("Makefile")`... Surprisingly it is returning the length of the string including the terminator.

Comment: But I wonder why would the string literal be interpreted as array in this case...

Comment: @EugeneSh. From _6.4.5 String literals_: "The multibyte character sequence is then used to initialize an **array** of static storage duration and length just sufficient to contain the sequence" and from _6.5.3.4 The sizeof and _Alignof operators_:  "When applied to an operand that has array type, the result is the total number of bytes in the array."

Comment: Note that if `argc != 1`, code attempts `printf("\n%s", NULL);`

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is

```
  strcpy(fileFlag, "-f");
```

`fileFlag` is one element short of the required space, you need to have 3 element-array to store `"-f"` along with the terminating null. In this case, as per the `strcpy()` behaviour,

> The `strcpy` function copies the string pointed to by `s2` (including the terminating null
>   character) into the array pointed to by `s1`. [...]

So, including the null-character, the size of the source is 3, so is needed for the destination also. Otherwise, you'll be accessing out of bound memory which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said,

- [please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).
- Always check for the success of `malloc()` before using the returned pointer.

Comment: @EugeneSh. wait, you mean to say it's not a pointer to the literal?

Comment: surprisingly, it is returning the length of the string.

Comment: @EugeneSh. OK, it's the `sizeof` which does not cause the decay. BY definition, string literals are _arrays of type char_, so that's It.

Comment: Well, that's the explanation, I guess.